# Will this binding be garbage collected?

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I have some custom JavaFx nodes connected with binding.
`SampleOne` and `SampleTwo` are custom JavaFX nodes. `SampleTwo` contains `SampleOne` in constructor and binds some property.

Is there any chance that a change in SampleTwo contentPosition property will not be visible by SampleOne's base (HBox)? I just want to be sure that all of the bindings will be alive all the time.

SampleOne.java - one of the custom nodes

```
public final class SampleOne {

    private final HBox base = new HBox();

    public SampleOne() {
        base.alignmentProperty().bind(contentPosition);
    }

    public HBox getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    //Properties

    private final ObjectProperty<Pos> contentPosition = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(SampleOne.this, "contentPosition", Pos.CENTER);

    public ObjectProperty<Pos> contentPositionProperty() {
        return contentPosition;
    }

    public void setContentPosition(Pos value) {
        contentPosition.set(value);
    }

    public Pos getContentPosition() {
        return contentPosition.get();
    }

    //... other properties

}
```

SampleTwo.java - another custom node that contains SampleOne in constructor

```
public final class SampleTwo {

    private VBox base = new VBox();

    public SampleTwo() {
        SampleOne sampleOne = new SampleOne();
        sampleOne.contentPositionProperty().bind(contentPosition);
        base.getChildren().add(sampleOne.getBase());
    }

    //Properties

    private final ObjectProperty<Pos> contentPosition = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(SampleTwo.this, "contentPosition", Pos.CENTER);

    public ObjectProperty<Pos> contentPositionProperty() {
        return contentPosition;
    }

    public void setContentPosition(Pos value) {
        contentPosition.set(value);
    }

    public Pos getContentPosition() {
        return contentPosition.get();
    }

    //... other properties

}
```

Comment: It appears everything important is strongly reachable, so you should be fine. Assuming you keep a strong reference to `SampleTwo` (or at least `SampleTwo.base`).

Comment: @Slaw let's say that SampleTwo.base (VBox) will be part of my `Scene`. In that case I guess it will be okay, thank you

Comment: I often test these by temporarily adding a listener to something which calls `System.gc()`, and make sure all the bindings still work after that. It’s not completely guaranteed to catch any of these “premature garbage collections”, but in practice it seems to work.

Comment: there's a nice little tool [JMemoryBuddy](https://github.com/Sandec/JMemoryBuddy) meant for doing the opposite (that is detect memory leaks) which can be used inversely :)